# Check multiple columns for duplicate and list all records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns ID, Content and Day. I am trying to find all rows that have duplicate Content and Day values and display **all** rows

```
SELECT ID,Content, `Day`, Count(*)
FROM table 
GROUP BY  Content,`Day`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The current code will return a list of duplicate Content and 'Day' values for instance:

```
ID|Content|Day
1 |   a   | 1 
2 |   a   | 1
3 |   a   | 1
4 |   b   | 2
5 |   b   | 2
6 |   c   | 3
7 |   c   | 4
```

Will result in:

```
ID|Content|Day|Count
1 |   a   | 1 | 3
4 |   b   | 2 | 2
```

But I want to display all the unique IDs as well;

```
ID|Content|Day
1 |   a   | 1 
2 |   a   | 1
3 |   a   | 1
4 |   b   | 2
5 |   b   | 2
```

Comment: JOin that query to the whole table

Comment: Glad you are getting help, But maybe you should start a SQL tutorial instead asking question every 12h. You would learn more and we still be here when you need help with the complicated stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a `Sub-Query`

```
select * 
from table 
where `day` in
( 
SELECT ID
FROM table 
GROUP BY  Content,`Day`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) A
```

Comment: Think you would need the sub query to return both content and day, and check _(content, `day`) IN_ the sub query.

Answer (score 1):

Use that query as a subquery to join against the table again:-

```
SELECT  table.ID, table.Content, table.`Day`
FROM table
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Content, `Day`, Count(*)
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY  Content,`Day`
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) sub0
ON sub0.Content = table.Content
AND sub0.`Day` = table.`Day`
```